# SQL Chain (joins and wheres) - Ruby

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, where-clause

I'm trying to make a search filter, and all params are the names of the check boxes so they are arrays filled with id values.

```
@sql_query = ''

if filters_benefit_type.nil? == false
  @sql_query = 'id_benefit_type = (:benefit_types)'
end

if filters_category.nil? == false
  if filters_benefit_type.nil? == false
    @sql_query = @sql_query + ' AND '
  end
  @sql_query = @sql_query + 'id_subcategory = (:company_subcategorys)'
end

if filters_zone.nil? == false
  if filters_category.nil? == false
    @sql_query = @sql_query + ' AND '
  end
  @sql_query = 'zone = (:zones)'
end

@companys = Company
  .joins(:subsidiary)
  .joins(:benefit)
  .where(@sql_query, 
    :benefit_types => filters_benefit_type, 
    :company_subcategorys => filters_category, 
    :zones => filters_zone
  )
```

And this throws me the following error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s):
```

Any ideas ? I guess I'm doing the .joins and .where wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Try chaining Relations:

```
@companies = Company.scoped
@companies = @companies.where(id_benefit_type: filter_benefit_type) if filter_benefit_type.present?
@companies = @companies.where(id_subcategory: filter_category) if filter_category.present?
@companies = @companies.where(zone: filter_zone) if filter_zone.present?
```

as long as the filters are empty or array of integers!

`where(column: [1,2,3])` gives the condition `where column in (1,2,3)`

**Addition**

the details of the where parts depend on the relationships of your models.
The column names did'n reflect that (at least, not in RoR style).
If i.e. Company `belongs_to :benefit_type, foreign_key: "id_benefit_type"`, my first example would work (the table of the companies would have a column `id_benefit_type`).

If Company `has_and_belongs_to_many :benefits`, and `Benefit` has an attribute `id_benefit_type`, you would need a join:

```
@companies = @companies.joins(:benefits).where(:benefits => {id_benefit_type: filter_benefit_type}) if filter_benefit_type.present?
```

Comment: Didn't work :S

`filters_benefit_type = params[:filter_benefit_type]
filters_category = params[:filter_category]
filters_zone = params[:filter_zone]
companies = Company.scoped
companies = companies.where(:id_benefit_type => filters_benefit_type) if filters_benefit_type.present?
companies = companies.where(:id_subcategory => filters_category) if filters_category.present?
companies = companies.where(:zone => filters_zone) if filters_zone.present?`

Error: 
' Unknown column 'tbl_companys.id_benefit_type' in 'where clause'